# How can I install Ubuntu on a Windows XP machine that will not connect to the Internet?

Tags: installation, windows

I have a former Windows 7 machine in which the hard drive failed. I bought a new hard drive and was forced to install Windows 2000 and upgrade to XP- it would not allow straight XP install. I do not have access to a more recent Windows OS install. I can't get 2000 off the hard drive now but I also can't get XP to connect to the Internet. I have heard great things about Ubuntu and figured now is as good a time as any to give it a shot. How can I get Ubuntu on the machine that won't connect to the Internet? I have a Windows 7 laptop that is connected if I have to download onto a DVD-R if needed. Please just tell me how. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, but this is going to be easier then it may seem. On your **Win7** machine, download an [ISO Disc Image of Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), mount it *(I think it already mounts it in most Image burning applications)*, then burn it with your favorite Disc Image Burning Application. Now, on your **XP** or **2000** or **Whatever** machine, boot the up the disc drive via the BIOS, then it should come up to setup.

You mentioned it would *not connect to the Internet*, which seems strange if your other laptop can connect. You can always try a **WiFi Adapter** or **Ethernet Cord**, but otherwise install Ubuntu and only used the unupdated and otherwise default software.